# SharePoint 2013: Connect Task List to Office 2007 not showing all tasks

Tags: 2013, outlook

I am trying to connect SharePoint 2013 task list with Outlook 2007.

I am a site collection administrator on the site. When I do that, only unassigned tasks appear in the tasks list in Outlook 2007.

When I try the same operation with office 2013, all of the tasks appear in the list tasks list in outlook.

I have checked the communication between SharePoint and Outlook using Fiddler and it is exactly the same so it is the Outlook application that seems to be processing the information differently.

I have gone through all the options but have not been successful in showing all the tasks.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Are you mean it's working with office 2013 as you need but not at office 2007 ? I am sorry I  can't understand what you specifically need to do ? :)